# VOSRDY bit never being set by hardware

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

Working with the [STM32H753ZI](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099-stm32h742-stm32h743753-and-stm32h750-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) I am following the sequence of setting the "VOS" into Vcore boost mode or "VOS0" to achieve the highest clock speed as possible.

In the reference manual a sequence is to be followed in order to get there.

[image]

As requested, I have followed all the procedure to get to "VOS0", however I am stuck at step 4. "Wait for VOSRDY" to be set. This bit never sets for me. I have tried everything. Re arranging orders. Any ideas?

Code:

```
void init_Clock() {

    //Obtaining 480 MHz
    //DIVM1: 4
    //DIVN1: 60
    //DIVP1: 2
    //D1CPRE: 1

    // FLASH_ACR
    // MASKING: FLASH_ACR
    FLASH -> ACR &= ~FLASH_ACR_LATENCY;
    FLASH -> ACR &= ~FLASH_ACR_WRHIGHFREQ;
    // WRITING: FLASH_ACR
    FLASH -> ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_4WS;
    FLASH -> ACR |= FLASH_ACR_WRHIGHFREQ_2;
    // CHECKING:
    if (((FLASH -> ACR) & (FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_4WS)) == FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_4WS){

    } else{
            //NO
    }

    // PWR_D3CR
    // MASKING:
    // PWR -> D3CR &= ~PWR_D3CR_VOS;
    // WRITING:
       PWR -> D3CR |=  PWR_D3CR_VOS1;

    // RCC_APB4ENR
    // MASKING:
       RCC -> APB4ENR &= ~RCC_APB4ENR_SYSCFGEN;
    // WRITING:
       RCC -> APB4ENR |= RCC_APB4ENR_SYSCFGEN;

    // SYSCFG_PWRCR
    // MASKING:
       SYSCFG -> PWRCR &= ~SYSCFG_PWRCR_ODEN;
    // WRITING:
       SYSCFG -> PWRCR |= SYSCFG_PWRCR_ODEN;

    // PWR_D3CR
    // WAITING:
       while (((PWR -> D3CR) & (PWR_D3CR_VOSRDY)) == 0){};

    // RCC_CFGR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_SW;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL1;

    // RCC_PLL1DIVR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLL1DIVR &= ~RCC_PLL1DIVR_P1;
    RCC -> PLL1DIVR &= ~RCC_PLL1DIVR_N1;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLL1DIVR |= RCC_PLL1DIVR_P1_2;
    RCC -> PLL1DIVR |= RCC_PLL1DIVR_N1_60;

    // RCC_PLLCKSELR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLLCKSELR &= ~RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM1;
    RCC -> PLLCKSELR &= ~RCC_PLLCKSELR_PLLSRC;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLLCKSELR |= RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM1_4;
    RCC -> PLLCKSELR |= RCC_PLLCKSELR_PLLSRC_HSI;

    // RCC_D1CFGR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> D1CFGR &= ~RCC_D1CFGR_D1CPRE;
    RCC -> D1CFGR &= ~RCC_D1CFGR_HPRE;
    RCC -> D1CFGR &= ~RCC_D1CFGR_D1PPRE;
    // Writing:
    RCC -> D1CFGR |= RCC_D1CFGR_D1CPRE_DIV1;
    RCC -> D1CFGR |= RCC_D1CFGR_HPRE_DIV2;
    RCC -> D1CFGR |= RCC_D1CFGR_D1PPRE_2;


    // RCC_D2CFGR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> D2CFGR &= ~RCC_D2CFGR_D2PPRE1;
    RCC -> D2CFGR &= ~RCC_D2CFGR_D2PPRE2;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> D2CFGR |= RCC_D2CFGR_D2PPRE1_DIV2;
    RCC -> D2CFGR |= RCC_D2CFGR_D2PPRE2_DIV2;

    // RCC_D3CFGR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> D3CFGR &= ~RCC_D3CFGR_D3PPRE;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> D3CFGR |= RCC_D3CFGR_D3PPRE_DIV2;

    // RCC_PLLCFGR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL1RGE;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL1VCOSEL;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL1RGE_8_16;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_Wide_VCO_Range;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_DIVP1EN;

    // RCC_CR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> CR &= ~RCC_CR_PLLON;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
    // WAITING:
    while ((RCC -> CR && RCC_CR_PLL1RDY) == 0){};
}
```

UPDATE: Got it working

As Brhans answer was setting the LDOEN bit first before touching the VOS bit.

Comment: Have you enabled the LDO? You have to do that before you can set VS0. PWR->CR3 - LDOEN bit.

Comment: @brhans THERE WE GO! Thank, hahah how did you know? I dont remember seeing that in the document.

Comment: Wait might have spoke to soon, testing still.

Comment: @brhans okay so, I found out that "LDOEN" is already set, however it doesnt work unless I set it to 0 then back to 1 again?

Comment: I've been working with a STM32H7xx device for the last few months. I remembered from skimming through the relevant bits of ST's HAL library that you had to turn on the LDO for max clock speed.

Comment: @brhans ah, the classic looking thru HAL code. Any ideas for the comment above?

Comment: Weird. I don't see anything in the HAL code to clear LDOEN before setting it. The guts of `HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(uint32_t SupplySource)` in stm32h7xx_hal_pwr_ex.c really only does `MODIFY_REG (PWR->CR3, PWR_SUPPLY_CONFIG_MASK, SupplySource);` after checking that the config is not locked, and then does a delay `while (__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG (PWR_FLAG_ACTVOSRDY) == 0U)`.

Comment: @brhans Yeah, so I checked the LDOEN bit without doing anything to do it and its already enable. But if you reset it it works hahah so weird man